# Bind data to specific blade templates in Laravel 5.1 (Issue with view composer being called twice on nested template)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to implement themes in a site so that certain pages have a different look and feel (and features) than other pages.

I have `master.blade.php` which contains the full HTML structure and has `@section` and `@yield` to get the content:

```
<html>
<body>

    @section('master-template')
    <?php
        view()->share('masterTemplate', 'general');
        $masterTemplate = "general"; 
    ?>
    @stop

    <header>
        @section('nav-1')
            @include('layout.navs.house-links')
        @show

        @section('nav-2')
            @include ('layout.navs.contact-links')
        @show

        @section('nav-3')
            @include('layout.navs.product-links')
        @show

        @section('nav-4')

        @show
    </header>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

I then have `ford.blade.php` which extends master, and overwrites some things:

```
@extends('templates.master')

@section('master-template')
    <?php
        view()->share('masterTemplate', 'ford');
        $masterTemplate = "ford"; 
    ?>
@overwrite

@section('nav-1')
    @include('layout.navs.house-links')
@overwrite

@section('nav-2')
    @include ('layout.navs.contact-links')
@overwrite

@section('nav-3')
    @include('layout.navs.product-links')
@overwrite
```

Then a regular page on the website will extend *master.blade*, and anything that requires the Ford navigation bar and colour scheme will extend the *ford.blade* template.

I then bound a view composer to `layout.navs.product-links` which gets the `$masterTemplate` variable from the view data and checks if it is one of our themes (like "ford"). If it is a regular page, it will bind vehicle ranges for all manufacturers to the view, and if it is a ford page, it will only bind the ford ranges to the page. The pseudo-code of the view composer is below:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    // Get the view data
    $viewData = $view->getData();

    // Check for $masterTemplate view variable
    if (isset($viewData['masterTemplate'])) {
        $template = $viewData['masterTemplate'];

        if ($template == "ford") {
            $ranges = $this->getRangesForManufacturer($template);
        }else {
            $ranges = $this->getRangesForAllManufacturers();
        }

        $view->with('ranges', $ranges);
    }
}
```

The problem is, because *ford.blade* extends *master.blade*, BOTH views get rendered behind the scenes. So the above view composer logic is useless because it runs twice on the "ford" page, once for *master.blade* and then again for *ford.blade*.

I proved this by checking the queries that are running using Laravel DebugBar.

1. How can I bind a variable `$masterTemplate` for use in all views (and partials) to check logic inside a view whether it is a "ford" or "general" page? I did it with `@section` and `@overwrite` in *ford.blade* but this seems to not work everywhere.
2. How can I use a view composer to bind data to a partial view that is `@include`d by *ford.blade* and *master.blade*, because *ford.blade* extends *master.blade* and so the view composer gets executed twice.

Comment: Is the @overwrite with identical content intentional (for the `navs`)?

Comment: Yes because we have mazda, nissan, skoda, etc where some don't require all of the navs, or need them in a different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, `@overwrite` might do what you told it to (except for `@stop` being enough, see [how to extend a layout](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-a-layout)).

As a workaround: How about a redesign where you have a `meta-master`-template which contains the general stuff and is extended by both the `ford` and the `master` (i.e. general) template, depending on which part you need? (You could then rename `master` to `general` and `meta-master` to `master`)

That would skip your problem, because only one would be defined in each instance.

Comment: Thanks, making a new "general" template and letting the general and ford template extend master solved my issues. The number of database queries reduced dramatically on the page, so thank you!

Comment: Good to hear that it helped.